# Point another content database from Site Collection

Tags: site-collection, backup, content-database

I am having site collection with its own content database in development and production environment. Now i am facing some issues in production side. I tried to take site backup and restore it in development environment but i can't do that because of sharepoint version problem. Now i am trying to get backup of production content database and restore that database in development SQL server. Is it possible to point my development instance to point production content database instead of its own database?
How can i achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

Your choices are to either make sure that the versions of SharePoint and SQL Server on your dev machine precisely match what is in production, right down the the Cumulative Update and/or hotfixes - or to use a third party tool to export the entire site into a neutral format and then reimport it into dev. The problem with the latter is that it is entirely possible that doing so will fix whatever it is you are trying to debug.

It is technically possible to have newer versions of SharePoint and SQL Server on Dev but doing so also introduces the possibility that one of the newer patches also fixes the issue you are trying to debug.

Comment: Is it possible to point another site content database for my site collection?

Comment: Sure, you only have to detach the current one and then attach the new one.  You might also need to restart IIS on your farm doing this though that isn't always required. see Dismount-SPContentDatabase and Mount-SPContentDatabase for the specifics.  However, the content database being mounted must still either match the version of SharePoint on the farm where it is being mounted or be from a slightly previous version (i.e. same base version but lower CU/SP)

Comment: But i tried in my dev env. I am getting 404 error. I just changed content database from central administration.

Comment: You need to do this via the command line as simply attaching it via Central Admin does not run the upgrade scripts (assuming Dev is a newer version)  Also, you need to make sure that there is only one root level site collection per web application as that will also cause the 404 issue.  You may also need to restart IIS after attaching the new database